# how to get access to a tab view controller from a view controller in it?

Tags: ios

I think the question header is very clear...

the vc in "a view controller", i mean a child of the tab view controller.

how to get access to a tab view controller from a view controller in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`tabBarController` property of `UIViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/tabBarController) for this purpose. If your view controller is not in a tab bar, then this property will be `nil`.